# Variable is sent once and fails the second time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code where an Admin of my website can edit information relative to other users.

When he enters that page, he can see the information of the user he selected. 
He can then edit the information.

When he is finished editing, he presses the button "Save" and the information goes to another page "edited.php", where the data is processed into the database, and then the page goes back to the edit page.

My problem is: I can edit the first time. When i try to edit a second time, i return to the edit page and no information is there. Nothing is selected from the database.

My edit.php page:

```
$admin=$_SESSION['admin'];      
$user=$_GET['nomeut'];
$colab = $_SESSION['colab'];

if ($admin){
   $admquery=mysql_query("SELECT nome, id from utilizadores where nome='$user' OR nome='$colab'");

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($admquery);
   $idd=$row['id'];
   $pp=mysql_query("select * from pp where id_user='$idd'");
   $hl=mysql_query("select * from hl where id_user='$idd'");
   $cfp=mysql_query("select * from cfp where id_user='$idd'");
   $ce1=mysql_query("select * from ce where id_user='$idd'");

   $_SESSION['idd']=$idd;
   $_SESSION['colab']=$user;
  }
```

The variable `$admin` determines the logged in user is an admin.
The variable `$user` detremines the user the admin selected.
The variable `$colab` receives the same of the user, but this time gotten from the edited.php page

Here is my edited.php page

```
$admin=$_SESSION['admin'];
$idd=$_SESSION['idd'];
$user=$_SESSION['colab'];

  if ($admin){
  for($i=0;$i<$ppcontadata;$i++){
    $dataquery="UPDATE pp SET data='$dataarray[$i]' where data='$prevarray[$i]' AND id_user='$idd' AND id_reg=$idregpp[$i]";
    $result1=mysql_query($dataquery);
}
```

The `$_SESSION['colab']` contians the name of the user. So it is sent to the edit.php page from the edited.php

But the information is displayed only once. 
Example: Main Page -> Edit.php (OK) -> Edited.php (OK) -> Edit.php (OK) -> Edited.php (OK) -> Edit.php (FAIL - Doesn't print the data relative to the user now)

Hope you understood everything. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on top of both pages?

Comment: yes. I have it in all pages

Comment: I echoed the $colab variable, and i got it the first time i return to the "edit.php" page, btu the second time i return to the page, the $colab has no value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved it.

I just added the $colab variable in the link of the header.

Thanks for the answers.